# SQL Query for Disabled Active Directory Accounts

Tags: sql, active-directory

I need to query AD to determine if a users account is disabled.

Using a similar query used in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251038/querying-active-directory-from-sql-server-2005)

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT sAMAccountName
FROM ''LDAP://DC=MyDC,DC=com,DC=uk''
WHERE objectCategory = ''Person''
AND objectClass = ''user'')
```

I believe to determine if an account is disabled I have to use the userAccountControl field somehow. I've tried several things but they don't seem to be working:

```
WHERE userAccountControl & 2 <> 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it did work... this would be an ID-10-T :p

Answer (score 12):

Inside OPENQUERY() :

> AND ''userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:''<>2

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT sAMAccountName
FROM ''LDAP://DC=MyDC,DC=com,DC=uk''
WHERE objectCategory = ''Person''
AND objectClass = ''user''
AND ''userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:''<>2)
```

Comment: The code above returns active users.  Awesome solution.  Much better to use inside OPENQUERY due to the 1000 row limit imposed by ADSI.

Comment: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.803 is the code for a BitWise AND operation
1.2.840.113556.1.4.804 is the code for a BitWise OR operation

Just in case anyone was wondering why there was a strange number in there and what it meant.

Also this is the better solution for the reasons the previous comment states.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
SELECT sAMAccountName
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT sAMAccountName, userAccountControl 
FROM ''LDAP://DC=MyDC,DC=com,DC=uk'' 
WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' 
AND objectClass = ''user''') 
WHERE userAccountControl & 2 <> 0; -- disabled
```