# Using Security Extension for certain reports only

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My team has a service deployed internally, and part of this service is a list of client accounts stored in a sql table. SSRS is hosted on another server and we have integration jobs which [will eventually] pull these client accounts (along with additional info) from our 3 production environments to this SSRS database.

Also on this SSRS database, I’m creating a new table that will be a mapping of domain accounts and client accounts. I need this table so I can filter my report based on which client accounts the logged on user is allowed to see.

Pretty simple so far.

The next requirement of this is that I need to restrict access to the report itself. I understand I could normally use a security group to do this, but that would result in two separate locations to manage permissions for one resource and this is what I want to avoid.
The solution I’m looking into is to create a security extension to validate the logged in user against the database, allowing them access to the folder/report if they exist in the table. Once in, I can then use that same table again to filter their results.
What I’m not sure of is 1) if this is the best solution and 2) can I use a security extension for just MY portion of the site. There are many other users and reports on this site that I don’t deal with and don’t want to conflict with those.

Comment: sorry, there wasn't a tag for SSRS n00b :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up an internal report parameter, called something like UserID, and set its default value to be the non-queried expression `=User!UserID` . (This user ID can be selected from the list of globals in the Edit Expression dialog.)

You could then add a cartesian/cross join to your users table in your query, with a selection condition based on your internal report parameter - eg. ...`and UserTable.ID = @UserID` . This would ensure that no records were returned if an unauthorised user was running the report.

Note that the `User!UserID` field will only return the user for interactively-run reports - in scheduled reports, this will be the account for the scheduling service.

Comment: I'm already pulling the =User!UserID parameter to automatically filter the report, but I want to also restrict access to the report before we get to that point.

Comment: Then the answer is 'no'. Access *to* the report is not controlled from *within* the report.

Comment: I don't want to control access to the report from within it, but I want to control access to the report from a database table using a security extension (which isn't report specific), but I don't want to affect other reports on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Could you fill the DB table automatically from AD? Then you can use the standard windows security, but still only do the administration in Active Directory.

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251038/querying-active-directory-from-sql-server-2005)

Comment: that's the way i'd go as well, after all AD is designed for user admin

Comment: the problem is I need to maintain a mapping of users to accounts (accounts that are internal to a service, not AD) which they will be allowed to see the reports on and I don't want to manage two lists.

Comment: Could you write a program that manages both the DB table with users and the AD security group? Writing to a DB is easy, and the AD part is described here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can't you restrict access to the report by using a security group (either in it's own folder or report level permissions). Use windows authentication in your datasource connection and filter you report retrieving your username using the sql function ORIGINAL_LOGIN?

Comment: I could use a SG to restrict access, but then I would have two lists to maintain for access. I need to maintain the database to map users with access to which accounts they can see and didn't want to maintain a redundant list of users to manage access to the report itself.