# Querying LDAP from SQL Server issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory, ldap

I'm having some trouble configuring a SQL statement to perform an openquery on LDAP from SQL Server. I followed the instructions as laid out here: [Querying Active Directory from SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251038/querying-active-directory-from-sql-server-2005) but I'm having some trouble putting the final pieces together.

Firstly, I didn't know where my LDAP server was. So I did a `nslookup` and found the default server as:

```
abc.domain.popo.local
```

I configured my `OPENQUERY` as

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI, 'SELECT * FROM ''LDAP://DC=abc,DC=domain,DC=popo,DC=local'' WHERE
objectCategory = ''User''')
```

However, I get an error saying that

> An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM 'LDAP://DC=abc,DC=domain,DC=popo,DC=local' WHERE objectCategory = 'User'" for execution against OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI".

What is the likely issue here? Am I setting up the `DC` incorrectly (because I don't even know what DC means)? Or is it more likely that I just have the wrong server altogether for LDAP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to query against a Windows Active Directory (which functionally appears as LDAP).  By default, AD will not allow anonymous querying - you have to authenticate with a trusted username and password.  Also, you need to check with your sysadmin to make sure you have the proper base value ("DC=abc,DC=domain,DC=popo,DC=local").

Comment: Would I need to specify the username/password even if I'm using Windows Authentication to run the query?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd be surprised if your credentials would get passed all the way through.  Setting the credentials explicitly would be something to try, at least.

Comment: This could be it. I don't think the security for the linked server was ever set up. I have to get an Admin to check the properties on the linked server

Comment: If he's in SQL SSMS with Windows Auth, there is nothing more that needs to be done unless Domain Admins have locked down AD. A basic user in AD has permissions by default to read quite a few attributes and properties. Anonymous - sure - they are blocked by default (even though you can set dsheuristics, etc to open that up)

Comment: It turns out it was a credential issue. The linked server wasn't set up correctly

Comment: Thanks this helped me. I set up the linked server security option "Be made using this security context" and specified a user & password created specifically for this AD connection.

Answer (score 1):

See Richard Mueller's [ADO / SQL search tips](http://www.rlmueller.net/SQLSyntax.htm) - do they help? (Richard's site is a real treasure trove of LDAP and Active Directory references and tips - highly recommended!)

From what I've seen on this site, you might be having the wrong `objectCategory` - try using `Person` instead of `User` (which I believe is an `objectClass`):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 
            'SELECT * FROM ''LDAP://DC=abc,DC=domain,DC=popo,DC=local'' 
             WHERE objectCategory = ''Person''')
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's got some good information but doesn't solve my current issue. It also failed with objectClass instead of objectCategory

Comment: @Rondel: what are you trying to select?? Maybe you need to select from a different starting point, e.g. `'SELECT * FROM ''LDAP://CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=popo,DC=local'' WHERE
objectCategory = ''User'''` or something like that....

Comment: Right now I am trying to get anything information I can from AD for Users but ultimately I only want displayNames and usernames.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that "abc" isn't the actual name of a domain controller in that domain; hence in that case your OPENQUERY should omit that and be:

`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI, 'SELECT * FROM ''LDAP://DC=domain,DC=popo,DC=local'' WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' AND objectClass = ''user''')`

Comment: Good to know. So if I have a bunch of servers abc.domain.popo.local, def.domain.popo.local etc, I should just be using **DC=domain,DC=popo,DC=local**

Comment: @Rondel - Yes you should be using a "serverless bind" as a best practice; otherwise you would be targeting a specific domain controller - if that server goes down your queries will fail