# SQL LDAP group querying

Tags: sql, sql-server, openquery

I just want to display all users of a group that may involved to other groups, But my query returns a null result. Can anyone tell me what is my wrong here?.

```
SELECT  cn
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,
        '<LDAP://DC=IPPM,DC=QC,DC=CA>;
        (&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)
        (!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GROUPE ACCES APPLICATION OAS GESTIONNAIRES,
        OU=OAS,OU=PROJET_COMMUN,OU=Applications,OU=Groupes,DC=IPPM,DC=QC,DC=CA));
        cn;subtree')
```

Comment: Please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1251038/4519059) ;).